# node version manager n does not recognize node installed on Mac

Tags: node.js

I have just happily installed **node** (v6.9.4) and the *node version manager* package **n** (2.1.3).

Both these packages are correctly installed as I can see if I run

```
node -v
```

and

```
n --version
```

When I just run

```
n
```

to get the current active version of node I get the following answer

```
Error: no installed version

  Usage: n [options/env] [COMMAND] [args]

  Environments:
    n [COMMAND] [args]            Uses default env (node)
    n io [COMMAND]                Sets env as io
    n project [COMMAND]           Uses custom env-variables to use non-official sources
.......
```

Any suggestion of what can be wrong would be appreciated

Comment: I'm guessing that n only manages versions of Node.js that were installed by n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full disclaimer: this is the first I've heard about `n`. I've only ever used [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which works quite well.

Steps to try to get `n` working for me:

```
> npm -g install n
> n latest
> n

// outputs:
ο node/7.4.0
```

Now here's where it gets tricky. Unlike `nvm`, which manages Node versions on a system-wide level, `n` appears to only manage its own local versions inside `/usr/local/n/versions/node/`. As such you need to use `n`'s syntax to get a specific version to run:

```
> n use 7.3.0 —version

// outputs:
v7.3.0
```